# How to create dynamic arrays based on json?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, oracle, dynamic-arrays

I have sql query, which returns 6 columns. One of the column is clob type and I insert into this column json. It looks like that:

[image]

I need to make a table using javascript oraz c#, which will be display all parts from json and the specified amount. It should looks like that:

[image]

Then I have to display this information using html, which will display my dynamic table.

I don't have any idea what is the best practises to implement things such like that and what should i start with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is too broad. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources exist to help you have a good experience here, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: And also please read [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/5947043) if you want to get a clearer understanding of why we can't really help you with this vague question. You need to explain more specifically where you're stuck. If you simply have no experience at all of extracting data from a database and displaying it in a web page, then you likely need to study some introductory tutorials for the platform of your choice (e.g. ASP.NET MVC or whatever you're using).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it as your JSON is flawed as the object contains duplicate `part` and `amount` keys.

```json
{"part":"aa","amount":1,"part":"bb","amount":3,"part":"cc","amount":5}
```

The duplicate keys will be ignored and only the latest kept and will be parsed as:

```json
{"part":"cc","amount":5}
```

You need to change your JSON to contain an array of objects such as:

```json
[{"part":"aa","amount":1},{"part":"bb","amount":3},{"part":"cc","amount":5}]
```

or to use unique keys in the object:

```json
{"parts":{"aa":1,"bb",3"cc"5}}
```

Once you do that, you can use `JSON_TABLE` in Oracle to parse the data and extract the values.

Such as:

```sql
SELECT name,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       move,
       percentage,
       COALESCE( aa, 0 ) AS aa,
       COALESCE( bb, 0 ) AS bb,
       COALESCE( cc, 0 ) AS cc,
       COALESCE( dd, 0 ) AS dd
FROM   (
  SELECT t.name,
         t.start_date,
         t.end_date,
         t.move,
         t.percentage,
         j.part,
         j.amount
  FROM   table_name t
         OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
           t.modeljson,
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             part   VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.part',
             amount INT          PATH '$.amount'
           )
         ) AS j
)
PIVOT (
  SUM( amount ) FOR part IN (
    'aa' AS aa,
    'bb' AS bb,
    'cc' AS cc,
    'dd' AS dd
  )
)
```

For the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (
  'xxx',
  DATE '2020-10-01',
  DATE '2020-11-01',
  9,
  30,
  '[{"part":"aa","amount":1},{"part":"bb","amount":3},{"part":"cc","amount":5}]'
);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE  | MOVE | PERCENTAGE | AA | BB | CC | DD
> :--- | :--------- | :-------- | ---: | ---------: | -: | -: | -: | -:
> xxx  | 01-OCT-20  | 01-NOV-20 |    9 |         30 |  1 |  3 |  5 |  0
> ```

*(Note: you will need to know all the unique parts beforehand so you can pivot them; if you require a dynamic pivot then you would be better doing this in your middle tier [i.e. C#] as it cannot be done in the database.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3cd9b497e697f3574c8c69b092ba1d96)*

Comment: I changed json as you mentioned but the things is that I don't know all the unique parts because it depends on name(the first column) and this parts can be really different so I can't do it using JSON_TABLE in oracle.

Comment: @AnnaStelmach Then you'll need to pivot the data outside the database and you would be better asking a new question with a [MRE] includin your C# code for getting the data from the database and the issues you are having with performing the pivot (StackOverflow is not a website where people write your code for you, you need to put the initial effort in and then ask for help with errors).